# Breaking a possible infinite loop in AWS step functions

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am writing a state machine with the following functionality.
start State -> Lambda1 which calls external service Describe API endpoint to get State attribute of item example "isOKay" or "isNotOkay" -> Choice state((depending on the state received) if "IsOkay" move to next state and if "isNotOkay" again call lambda1. This happens until it gets a IsOkay state. How can put a limit to this custom retry loop so that I dont get stuck if I never receive a IsOkay response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use input your step in a form of counter, which incremented by lambda. Which when return in retry can be checked for a limit, if crosses one fail lambda with custom exception. Describe separate step for handling the exception.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).